# Multiple active TileLayers rather than just one?

Tags: leaflet, tile-layer

I was wondering if it's possible to use multiple TileLayers in leaflet at the same time, rather than just having one active? A bit like group layers. In my map I have a base map, and I would like to make another TileLayer with transparent PNG:s where I can have roads, names of places, and so on.

Right now I am following this tutorial to achieve what I want: 
https://www.hreikin.co.uk/2018/06/07/user-guide-how-to-create-an-interactive-campaign-map-with-leafletjs/

Basically I am working with the following tools:
Leaflet as base for the map
Zoomify (software) http://www.zoomify.com/ to creat the map Tiles from the image I have made in Photoshop.

The base tile looks like this in the code:

```
var layer = L.tileLayer.zoomify('./basemap/{g}/{z}-{x}-{y}.jpg', {
    width: 19000,    // MUST be defined.
    height: 10688,   // MUST be defined.
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 7,
    continuousworld: false,
    noWrap: true,
}).addTo(map);
```

Then I have a bunch of markers for cities that are grouped into layers. What I currently would want to do is to make multiple basemaps as layers, rather than toggleable.

As you can see on the layer icon in the top right corner you can only have one active basemap at a time: https://hreikin.co.uk/interactive-campaign-map/interactive-campaign-map.html

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! what software are you using? Please update your question using  the [edit] button or add a relevant tag.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: @IanTurton I have answer so I propose reopening.

Comment: The map panes tutorial at https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/ literally uses several `L.TileLayer`s, so the answer is "yes".

Comment: It’s ready for you @TomazicM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mentioning group layers in your question and that's actually the right solution for what you want to achieve. You can group several tile layers in one group and add it to the map as single layer.

To have those layers displayed in the right order one above other, map panes, mentioned by @IvanSanchez (https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/), can be used.

Vertical order of panes is controlled by `zIndex` property of pane. By default tile layers are assigned to `tilePane` pane, which has `zIndex` value of 200. Next pane above it is `overlayPane` with `zIndex` values of 400, to which all vector overlays are assigned. This tells you you have `zIndex` values between 200 in 400 available for ordering of tile layers in your group layer.

To achieve what you want, first you create map panes with desired `zIndex` values, then assign layers to those panes and in the last step create base group layer and add it to the map, with optional overlays.

So let's say you have tile layers `layer1`, `layer2` and `layer3`, that you want to combine in single base layer, where `layer3` should be at the bottom, followed by `layer1` and `layer2`.

```
map.createPane('paneForLayer1');
map.createPane('paneForLayer2');

map.getPane('paneForLayer1').style.zIndex = 210;
map.getPane('paneForLayer2').style.zIndex = 220;

var layer1 = L.tileLayer.zoomify( ..., {pane: 'paneForLayer1', ... }); 
var layer2 = L.tileLayer.zoomify( ..., {pane: 'paneForLayer2', ... });
var layer3 = L.tileLayer.zoomify( ..., { ... });

baseLayer = L.layerGroup([layer1, layer2, layer3]);
map.addLayer(baseLayer);

.
.
.

L.control.layers(
  {'Base layer': baseLayer},
  {'Overlay1': overlay1, 'Overlay2': overlay2}
).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!